# Azure Insert Script - Could not find symbol 'require'

Tags: mobile, azure, service, require

I'm just started working with BLOB Storage on Azure and I'm trying to implement Image Uploads to BLOB Storage using this tutorial for Windows Phone 8: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-upload-data-blob-storage/?fb=de-de

In step 6 of this tutorial there is a insert script for a table, which needs to be set, instead of the generic one. It starts with:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var qs = require('querystring');
var appSettings = require('mobileservice-config').appSettings;
```

However, when I simply copy this script into my table's insert script i always get the error "Could not find symbol 'require'", which is weird, because it should be an azure function. Searching the web hasn't brought me any result.

Ansy suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the error just showing up in the script editor, or are you actually getting this in the log when you try to invoke the API?

Comment: It shows in the script editor and when i run my app and try to insert into the table I get an InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Could not find symbol 'require'" in the Azure portal script editor is just a bug in how that environment validates the script - it shouldn't affect the actual operation of the service itself. See [Phillip Van Nortwick's reply in the Azure forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c173c8b7-ee21-4bda-9799-65835304f7ea/previously-working-mobile-service-server-side-scripts-no-longer-working?forum=azuremobile).

It's likely that your InvalidOperationException is coming from other error. Have you tried calling an api with thise require()s defined and otherwise empty code?

Comment: No I haven't. I will try and do that and let you know, if it works.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Should have tried that before. The error was at some other place in the code.